# Issue when changing Locale to ARABIC in Android application

Tags: android, kotlin, configuration, locale, arabic

My Android application supports two languages: Arabic and English. Arabic is the default language.

Now, to make Arabic as default language, i am changing my app locale to Arabic in Splash Screen. And i have maintained both English and Arabic string files for the locale change. But, when i click on some other random fragments (eg. Navigation menu item), my app static strings changes back to English locale.

I assume this is because my app default locale might have been changed to English. This issue is generated randomly, no specific scenarios are noted.

Can you suggest any solution?

Edit: I am using Shared preferences to save the language.

Answer (score 0):

First step you wand to save the language in your sqlite (ex: language saved in table settings at sqlite):

```
mDatabase = new SqliteItemDatabase(getApplicationContext());

        final List<Setting> allsettings = mDatabase.listSettings();
       String the_lang = "";
       if(position == 0)
       {
           the_lang = "en";


       }
        else if(position == 1)
        {
            the_lang = "ar";


        }
LocaleHelper.setLocale(LAngSelect.this, the_lang);// =>set language

        mDatabase.updateSettings(new Setting(allsettings.get(0).getId(),the_lang));
mDatabase.close();
```

Second step: to set activity right-to-left you want to add in every activity:

```
 mDatabase = new SqliteItemDatabase(this);
        final List<Setting> allsettings = mDatabase.listSettings();
        String langs = allsettings.get(0).getLang() ;
        if(langs.equals("ar")) {
            //HERE CHECK CONDITION FOR YOUR LANGUAGE if it is AR then
//change if it is english then don't
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
                //Resources res = getResources(); //resource handle

            }
        }
```

Comment: This might be a solution, but i strictly don't want to use/rely on sqlite database. I am using Shared preference instead to save my locale language. And when the default language is set to ARABIC, i am not facing any issues related to  "right-to-left" support, as i have given value true to rtl support in Manifest file. So no need to do extra coding for that. If you have any other solution then suggest. Thanks.

Comment: when you choose arabic language force the app to go to mainactivity, and in mainactivity get the language(lang) and write:          LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, langs);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i am doing the same. Still it gets back to English randomly sometimes.